# To generate random UUID which is 2 Digit Long

Tags: c++, boost

I am Using Boost Random generator to generate Random UUID's.The Random UUID that i generate now is quite Lengthy.Instead i want to generate a UUID which is a 2 Digit like for eg:"Dz"

The Line of Code i am using now is

std::string strAK = to_string( boost::uuids::random_generator()() );

How to Modify this code and Generate a UUID which is 2 digit long.

Comment: there's a reason why a UUID is so long.....

Comment: Generate something that's two digits long if you must. Just don't call it a UUID, and don't expect to avoid clashes.

Comment: Taking a step back, what are you going to be doing with this 2 character string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivially,

```
std::string strAK = to_string( boost::uuids::random_generator()() ).substr( 0, 2 );
```

but as has already been commented, this isn't going to be universally unique.

Comment: It isn't even likely to be unique over the range this 2 char string could potential represent, depending on the base (i.e 36 for all upper alpha and 0-9). If he truly only needs 2 chars to cover all possibilities, it might be better to use an auto incrementing  counter which would give 100 possible combinations or if he needs more than that convert the decimal number to a different base.

Comment: Thanks Philip...As u rightly said,It would be wrong to call the 2 digit ID as UUID.I need it because i already have a typical UUID and i need the 2 digit ID to link to this inside a map...